# Share user location to Google+ API

Tags: geolocation, google-plus, google-latitude

After Google Latitude retirement I got a question is there any way to share user device location to Google+ thought Google API?

I'm trying to implement "Share Location" feature which Android devices have out-of-the-box. (https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2998354)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to set a user's location in Google+, there is however a very *primitive* way to read a user's location, as mentioned here:
[Future of Google Location History API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589718/future-of-google-location-history-api)

There is no replacement or workaround for the current Google Latitude API functionality.