# Does Google expose "Find my Device" APIs?

Tags: rest, google-api, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

Google has its "Find my Device" service allowing you to find your phone, make it ring (even when silenced), remotely wipe it, etc. by entering here: https://myaccount.google.com/find-your-phone

What I would like to know is if there is an API exposing these functions for others to use them.

I am specially interested in the "ring" feature, I do not really need location data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Google offer an API that I can use to get the location of my phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914821/does-google-offer-an-api-that-i-can-use-to-get-the-location-of-my-phone)

Comment: While the question you point out is pretty similar, I am not really interested in the location data, but in the ring feature. I have edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: FWIW, I'm also really interested in this ringing feature.

Comment: Did you find a solution to trigger "find my phone" via a web call?

Comment: Could somebody edit this question and try to get attention from google devs? According to this: [How to get help](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/support) we should have `[google-contacts]` tag in this question.
I am considering requesting new feature but for this I would like to make sure that this api is really not available.

Comment: I'm also interested in ring API. I want to put the button on the wall which will ring my phone and help me to find it. Strange Goble didn't provide such a straightforward feature out-of-the-box.