# Get all my google cookie given username and password

Tags: cookies, google-account

I am working on my final degree project. I want to show to a user that logged in my website, and gave me his user and password to his google account, his google location history. in [this](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2014/04/extracting-your-own-location-information-from-google-the-hard-way/) tutorial he almost made it but the cookies sniffing action will work for a single user and not for many users.

I would like to save to a file all my google account cookies, Programmatically. thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Future of Google Location History API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589718/future-of-google-location-history-api)

Comment: not realy, i'm asking how to get the cookies, it doesn't answer that.

Comment: Don't do that.  (if you manage to do that successfully, you will be caught by Google's abuse systems)

Comment: it's only school dummy POC, it won't be tried more than 30-40 times.

Comment: This is definitively against the terms.