# How can i get google location history/ google map timeline data?

Tags: android, location

in one of my current app's i have a requirement that, i need to get location history from user mobile. In google maps android app there is a option called "Timeline" in that i can see all the location of user which he traveled. I want these list.
Is there any google API to get the location history. Can anyone help me or guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589718/future-of-google-location-history-api

Comment: Google Fit: https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history

Comment: @HedeH I'm asking about Location history not Fitness history.

Comment: You also have location history api there.. I use it myself. It gives you more or less the same data Google Maps is collecting. The user has to approve the normal location permission and a Google Fit location permission. If you are interested I can post an example.. But it's not a quick solution, it takes time to implement correctly...

Comment: Hey NutKac, i have gone through that link before posting this question, but i could not get the solution from that. Did you try from that link.

Comment: Regarding my last comment - One important thing - Using google Fit you need to trigger location monitoring, And the history you will get is from that point and on. So you can't register a user to Google Fit for the first time and get the locations of yesterday...